# How can I pad a laptop-sized bag to improve safety for a laptop?

Tags: safety, moving, laptop

I have a backpack with a laptop compartment (the top half of this compartment can be opened with a zipper). That compartment is just about the right size for my laptop that I would like to carry in said backpack.

However, the backpack as such does not appear to be particularly padded in any way; at least, it appears to be less padded than typical laptop bags.

**What is a good way to add some additional protection for my laptop that will decrease the risk of physical damage during my daily commute from e.g. bumping the backpack against a wall on a crowded train?**

I am looking for a solution that fulfils the following requirements:

- It should be some padding or similar on the inside of the backpack that does not take much space, so as to not decrease the internal backpack size too much (maybe just parts of padding placed at strategic points?).
- The padding should in some way be fixed within the backpack, so it doesn't require rearranging every time I pack/unpack the laptop.
- It should not make my luggage disproportionately heavier.

Comment: For what you would spend on materials, you could use a padded sleeve, sized to fit your model laptop. I'm not sure this rated or required a lifehacks solution.

Comment: @Stan: Basically, any solutions that come out of the bag with the laptop (as an additional layer that has to be unpacked) are impractical, given that I intend to unpack and repack the laptop during my daily commute - that is, on trains where I do not have ample space around the very seat I sit on to handle and arrange several loose objects.

Answer (score 5):

A layer of high-density, low-rebound foam (material like Sorbothane is very good) on each side of the laptop, backed with a glued-on layer of something rigid and strong, like fiberglass reinforced sheet, should do the job.  Make the padding a little bigger than the laptop, the rigid sheet a little bigger than that (ideally, the same size as the inside of the bag, so it doesn't move around), and then glue a border made of a second layer of the foam to keep the laptop inside the padding.  This assembly should add no more than 1/2 inch (about 13 mm) to the thickness of the laptop.

You can leave the halves loose, glue them to the inside of the bag, or make hinges from nylon webbing (which works best depends on the bag design and size); either way, the laptop will easily slip out when the pad/case assembly is opened, but will stay securely in place when the bag is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping your needs into consideration, you can wrap your laptop with 2 layers of bubble wrap before placing inside your laptop slot so that it does not take much space nor make it heavier and provides a layer of protection from scratches. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but make sure you have static-free plastic!

Comment: I have done this using fleece - the stuff they make hoodies out of. Maybe you could recycle a worn-out hoodie?